# Is it possible to transfer methods, defined in mongoose schema, to client side?

Tags: methods, express, mongoose, schema

when using mongoose with express under node.js, suppose I have a cool function, defined server-side on a mongoose model, and I find that function would be very useful on the client-side too. Is it possible to transfer it to the client-side? Some settings for toJSON options? Is it possible or feasible at all? I think it would be pretty object oriented. Currently methods, defined on a mongoose schema are only available on the objects server-side. But what if want to have those methods available on my model instances client-side? I dont want to redefine them once again in ui controllers and such. wanna keep DRY. is that possible? Do you find the idea feasible at all?

thanks!